# Gitflow and Accidently Merging other features

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-flow, feature-branch

We've recently started to introduce gitflow, following mainly some youtube videos and some online articles - along with the GUI functionality within SourceTree.

However we think we're doing something wrong as we're hitting situations which we were hoping to resolve.

`developer 1` is working on `feature 1`, `developer 2` is working on `feature 2`, the `develop` branch is for development and is staging, the `master` branch is live/production

### developer 1

1. **develop = master (in sync with master)**
2. **develop -> branch to feature-1**
3. **develop <- merged in feature-1**

### developer 2

1. **develop != master (isnt in sync with master)**
2. **develop -> branch feature-2**
3. **develop <- merge feature-2**

Now we come to the problem, if `developer 2` wants to put `feature 2` live by merging it into `master` - it will contain `feature 1`, meaning they'll both go live.

So we're clearly doing something wrong - and this is what we need clarification from, the only 2 ways I can see around this off the top of my head are

- You create the new features from `master` rather than `develop`
- You use "Cherry Pick" which only takes the actual changed files into `master`

---

The solution we want is for mixture of web development projects that do not have release cycles, they literally go live once the client has signed off the feature, so suggestions on how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is `develop`? A branch? The way your question is put now, it is unclear why you think that developer 2 merging `feature 2` would contain `feature 1` as well.

Comment: yes it's a branch - it will contain feature 1 because developer 1 has merged feature 1 into develop, shortly after developer 2 branches from develop for his feature 2 - feature 1 was merged into develop as it was ready for UAT from the client

Comment: Why wouldn't you want feature 1 to go live (together with feature 2) ? When developer 1 merged feature 1 back onto develop, it should have been production ready.

Comment: it could be production ready - but that doesn't mean the client has approved it to go live

Answer (score 1):

Well, as per the gitflow documentation http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ :

> Finished features may be merged into the `develop` branch to definitely add them to the upcoming release

So dev 1 should not merge `feature 1` into `develop` until it is 100% guaranteed in the next release. And if that is the case, then it's no problem for dev 2 to branch off of that, including `feature 1`. When `feature 1` is in `develop`, then it should be considered "done" except for bugfixes, it cannot easily be removed from `develop`.

That said, I find gitflow cumbersome and prefer http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/ myself. Besides being structurally much cleaner, it has the huge benefit that it is trivially easy to back out features from the "next release" at any point, and that the "problem" you are facing (one feature implicitely bringing along another one) cannot occur.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - however the problem I mention says there are no release cycles - so the above mentioned gitflow way does not work, because of the original issue

Comment: Both workflows do not care whether you have long planned cycles or "ad hoc" releases...

Answer (score 1):

When developer 1 merged feature 1 back onto develop, it should have been production ready.

Therefore there shouldn't be a problem realeasing feature 2 and feature 1 together.

But you have a few options here.

1. Don't finish feature 1 just yet (if it's not production ready, don't merge it back onto `develop`).
2. Release more often (release feature 1 first, as soon as it is finished).
3. Use feature toggling (have a property `feature1.enabled=false`) and release feature 1 along with feature 2, although the functionality is disabled.

Remember that under `git flow`, releases are always made from `develop` branch, so you should ideally be able to do a release from `develop` with production ready code pretty much whenever you want.

Comment: Hi - the same issue as the above suggestion - the issue is there are no release cycles - its when the client wants that feature to go live it goes live

Comment: See point 1: if it's not produciton ready (or if client doesnt want the feature live yet), don't merge it back onto `develop`, or point 3: feature toggling